# Error message when creating docker container

Tags: docker

I'm trying to create a new docker container using the following command:

```
docker run -d -it --name compsci -v /c/Users/garre/Documents/CPSC_Courses:/homechapmanfse/computing-resources:cs_base
```

However, it gives me this error message:

```
"docker run" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker run --help'.


Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]

Run a command in a new container
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: Is there a colon, instead of a space, before `cs_base` in your command?

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide the name of the image that you want to run. This is currently missing in your command.

For example, if I were to run mysql, I would execute this:

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql
```

See the last argument, `mysql`? That is the name of the image.

Answer (score 2):

Think that you it has build image in your machine. You must inform name of image run.

```
docker run image-name
```

This command *--name* is necessary only you specific name for your container. And the *-it* command must be entered only when entering the executed container.

Answer (score 0):

`docker run -d -it -v
 /c/Users/garre/Documents/CPSC_Courses:/homechapmanfse/computing-resources:cs_base
 --name 'the name you want to give' 'official name of the image'`